# Is it possible to build something like a recurrent neural network for time-series data?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network

For example, if the data is an acceleration, each input is the acceleration at a time T ?

[image]

More precisely, I'm curious if I can have the same behavior of a recurrent neural network but only with a *normal* artificial neural network which has "inputs over time".

*In fact, I tried something like that and it doesn't work on my problem (but a RNN works). So I wonder if there is a mathematical explanation of why is it limited, why it may never have the same results?*

Comment: Check out reservoir computing, such as liquid state machine and echo state network. Sounds similar to what you say.

Comment: Could you edit to tell us what do you mean by "imputing the same data over time"? Your description is very vague and makes it hard to answer.

Comment: Hi @Tim, I added a schema and, I hope, a sufficiently detailed description

Comment: @dan32 so you mean applying NNs to something like time-series data?

Comment: Yes! If I understand correctly, in the case of a RNN we just input our data at the current time, and we modify the inside memory with this input when it learns. So I guess that a RNN has a memory over time, depending on the before inputs.
But if I just need a short term memory (which is the case for a RNN, no?), can I just input my data at the current time, but also the 50 past values of my input?

Comment: Check https://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/3

Comment: Thank you @Tim. Since "time series" is finally the keyword in my question, I could oriented my researchs and I found that TDNN (Time Delay Neural Network) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_delay_neural_network is possibly what I search for. But resources on this subject seems to be in less quantity than RNN.

Comment: Thank you @KolyaIvankov I will take a look a reservoir computing, that seems interesting!

Answer (score 2):

What you're suggesting is similar to regression approach to time series. For instance, you can recast the AR(1) process as a simple regression:
$$y_t=\beta_0+\phi_1y_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t$$
will become OLS problem:
$$y_i=X_i\beta+\varepsilon_i$$
where the independent variable $y_i\equiv y_t$and design matrix has two columns for intercept and bona fide one regressor $x_{1i}=1,x_{2i}=y_{i-1}$

This can be made work under certain conditions. Assumptions of OLS are slightly different (relaxed), of course.

Similarly, you could build the NN with one input which is the lagged dependent variable, which outputs the one step forecast. You'd have to call it repeatedly to produce the multi-step forecast. In this case your NN would basically degenerate into the glorified nonlinear regression $y_t=f(y_{t-1})+\varepsilon_t$

Comment: Thank you! But I'm afraid that I don't really understand the maths you wrote, I don't get the link between all the maths behind a NN and the equations you wrote... Can you enlighten me ?